# ReactiveUI The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

If I use a binding in code behind, getting an error after click at change IsBusy

```
"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"
```

xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="AsyncCommand"
                    Height="20"
                    Content="PushAsync"/>
<ProgressBar x:Name="IsBusy"
              Height="20"/>
```

cs:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.IsBusy, x => x.IsBusy.IsIndeterminate);
this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.AsyncCommand, x => x.AsyncCommand);
```

viewmodel:

```
public class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            AsyncCommand = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
            AsyncCommand
                .RegisterAsyncFunction(x => 
                 { IsBusy = true; Thread.Sleep(3000); return "Ok"; })
                .Subscribe(x => { IsBusy = false; });
        }

        private bool isBusy;

        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return isBusy; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.IsBusy, ref isBusy, value); }
        }
        public ReactiveAsyncCommand AsyncCommand { get; protected set; }
    }
```

But if I make a bind in xaml all works, like this:

cs:

```
DataContext = new TestViewModel();
```

xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="AsyncCommand"
                    Height="20"
                    Content="PushAsync"
                    Command="{Binding AsyncCommand}"/>
<ProgressBar x:Name="IsBusy"
              Height="20"
              IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public TestViewModel()
{
    AsyncCommand = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
    AsyncCommand.Subscribe(_ => IsBusy = true);

    AsyncCommand
        .RegisterAsyncFunction(x => 
         { Thread.Sleep(3000); return "Ok"; })
        .Subscribe(x => { IsBusy = false; });
}
```

Or even better:

```
ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _IsBusy;
public bool IsBusy {
    get { return _IsBusy.Value; }
}

public TestViewModel()
{
    AsyncCommand = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
    AsyncCommand
        .RegisterAsyncFunction(x => 
         { Thread.Sleep(3000); return "Ok"; })
        .Subscribe(x => { /* do a thing */ });

    AsyncCommand.ItemsInFlight
        .Select(x => x > 0 ? true : false)
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsBusy);
}
```

Comment: How do I invoke a synchronous method on UI thread from a `WhenAnyValue`?

Comment: Found my answer [here](https://reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/framework/ui-thread-and-schedulers). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your ViewModel property is implemented similiar to this:

```
public TestViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return (TestViewModel)DataContext; }
    set { DataContext = value; }
}
```

In that case, when you click button, lambda function from your `RegisterAsyncFunction` is called on non-UI thread. In `IsBusy = false` instruction ReactiveUI invokes ViewModel property which tries to get DataContext on non-UI thread, which causes `InvalidOperationException`.

If you bind your ViewModel to View in Xaml, then ViewModel property isn't called.

To fix this code you should use [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) to call `IsBusy = false`:

```
AsyncCommand
    .RegisterAsyncFunction(x => 
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>IsBusy = true); 
        Thread.Sleep(3000); 
        return "Ok"; 
    })'
```

Comment: This is incorrect advice for ReactiveUI (though you've got the core bug correct)

Comment: You don't want your VM to know about `Application`.